# Where can I find a bus map for Jerusalem, Israel?

Tags: public-transport, israel, maps, jerusalem

Where can I get a map of the bus system in Jerusalem? I'd prefer a paper one, but a digital one will do.

Comment: http://www.jlembusmap.com/

Comment: Not a map, but moovit is good

Answer (score 4):

Dated September 2016, Mapsta has

> The [newest official Jerusalem Transportation Map](http://www.mapsta.net/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Jerusalem-transport-map.pdf) was produced a few years ago (2012) by the Jerusalem Transport Master Plan team. The pdf map includes the network of bus routes in Jerusalem, express bus routes, the light train route, and ‘park and ride’ locations. Click the map below to see the map. It’s a big pdf file, so it may take a few seconds to open.

Answer (score 4):

Jerusalemites use the website [Egged](http://egged.co.il) to make trip plans.
You can also download the app "Efobus" which will give you up to date real time buses based on your location.
Google Maps is also okay in helping you navigate where things are.

Answer (score -1):

YOu can find it in Oren's Transit Page

Jerusalem Bus Map
Welcome to the Jerusalem Bus Map at Oren’s Transit Page. This fully interactive, unofficial map can be viewed in Google Maps and contains route information for many bus routes in Jerusalem and the surrounding area, as well as the Jerusalem Light Rail.

What is included on the Jerusalem Bus Map?
The map shows all routes where “Code 62” fares are valid:

Intracity lines within Jerusalem
Night Lines/Kavei Lilah
Suburban lines to Ma’ale Adumim, Mevaseret Zion, Givat Ze’ev, Ora, Aminadav, Even Sapir, Almon/Anatot, Kochav Yaakov, Tel Zion, Adam, and Kever Rachel (Rachel’s Tomb)
Jerusalem Light Rail (route and station locations)
The map also indicates the location of major destinations throughout the city (transportation centers, neighborhoods, major streets, and other points of interest) and which lines stop at each of those locations.